# Use alpha channel from texture as specular map?

Tags: three.js

Is there a way to get MeshPhongMaterial to use the alpha channel of the diffuse colour texture as the specular map rather than having to use a separate texture? I would think this would be quicker to load and more efficient to render (requiring 1 less texture unit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`MeshPhongMaterial` supports a specular map as a separate texture only. Currently, the specular map is grayscale only.

three.js r.71